# How to create an association table?

Tags: python

I have an excel file, in one column, I have symptoms.

My job is to create a new excel file where every symptom is crossed with the other, so I can calculate the support, confidence and lift of every association.

The original excel file has more than 1500 different symptoms. So the association excel would be very big.

Does anyone now how I should do this?

I would like to have a table with:

symptom1 - symptom2

symptom2 - symptom3

symptom1 - symptom3

Comment: How does your original data look like? It is nice if you can provide a small example data. And what have you ever tried?

Comment: You could use the SQL toolkit named SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create another column with all the other symptom use:

```
df = pd.read_excel(my_file)
df['key'] = 1
df = df.merge(df.rename({'sympthom': 'symptom2'}, axis=1), how='outer').drop('key', 
axis=1)
df = df[df['symptom'] < df['symptom2']] # to remove duplicates
df.to_excel('new_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Now in 'new_file' you will have two columns with all the symptom matches

Comment: I always get this error: "['key'] not found in axis"

Why are you doing df['symptom'] = 1? (Btw symptom is the column where all the symptoms are)

Comment: Are you sure you wrote: `df['key'] = 1` as in the code, and not `df['symptom'] = 1`?

Comment: Wow, you are my hero! Thanks!!! <3

Comment: Now I want to add to the calculated file (with all associations) add a new column with the support for each item (how many time it appears / total)